# Errors, Failed Connections, during Azure load tests - whitelist IPs?

Tags: performance, azure, load, performance-testing

I am trying to eliminate errors and failed connection attempts during the use of Azure Performance Load testing.  I believe I need to find the correct IP addresses to whitelist as when the Web App is restricted to specific IPs, we see the issues that do not occur when IPs are unrestricted.

We see 403 forbidden errors - and, almost exactly 1/2 of the connections show as failed attempts during the testing.  We use a whitelist to allow access to our dev web site from only certain IPs.  When I remove the IP restrictions, the tests work fine.

If I'm on track, I need to know which IPs to whitelist.  This is for the South Central US.

Azure does provide a [Datacenter IP Ranges article](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=41653), however, there are two problems:  1) There is no indication of which IPs are for Performance load testing.  And, 2) I see no way of importing the entire article if IPs - which I would happily do at this time.